# Translating PSQL expression to Laravel Eloquent Builder expression

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I am trying to return some result set

The PSQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM example
WHERE foo='abc'
AND (
  bar='x'
  OR
  bar='y'
)
AND NOT (
  id = ANY (array_of_ids)
);
```

This returns the correct set of rows, not including any rows that have an id in the `array_of_ids` but also, importantly, does not return any rows where `bar=z`

I've attempted the following with Eloquent's query builder:

```php
DB::table("example")
    ->where("example.foo", "=", "abc")
    ->whereNotIn("example.id", $array_of_ids)
    ->OrWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where("example.bar", "=", "x")
            ->where("example.bar", "=", "y");
    })
    ->distinct()
    ->select("example.id");
```

Unfortunately, this both includes those rows that have an id in the `array_of_ids`, and also includes rows where `bar=z` which is undesired.

I've tried moving where the `whereNotIn` call is, as follows:

```php
DB::table("example")
    ->where("example.foo", "=", "abc")
    ->OrWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where("example.bar", "=", "x")
            ->where("example.bar", "=", "y");
    })
    ->whereNotIn("example.id", $array_of_ids)
    ->distinct()
    ->select("example.id");
```

But the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your sql, I do not see any `or`...
however, `or` should be in `example.bar` comparison only ...
so, to get the same result using Query Builder, I think your query builder should look like:

```
 DB::table("example")
            ->where("example.foo", "=", "abc")
            ->where(function($query) {
                $query->where("example.bar", "=", "x")
                    ->orWhere("example.bar", "=", "y");
            })
            ->whereNotIn("example.id", $array_of_ids)
            ->distinct()
            ->select("example.id");
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much! There is an `OR` clause in the SQL query `AND ( bar='x' OR bar='y')` --- In any case, your query builder is exactly what I needed. Thank you, I misunderstood how `orWhere` should function. I will accept your answer as soon as I am able to.